# Plotting multiple time series in 1 graph using GGPLOT2 and grouping dates by week OR month

Tags: r

I like R but simple plotting is driving me mad. I have a 5 columns of data. The 1st column of data has dates in "numeric" the format 20101101, 20101102, etc...I tried converting from numeric to date but it didn't work.

I'd like to make a line graph with col1, col2, col3 and col4 and with the dates on the x axis by week or month. I don't want to see all the dates just every week or every month. Can you help?

Here is my R code:

```
dates<-c(20101101,20101102,20101103,20101104,20101105,20101106,20101107,20101108,20101109,20101110,20101111,20101112,20101113,20101114,20101115,20101116,20101117,20101118,20101119,20101120)  <br/>
col1<-c(seq(from=1,to=20, by=1))<br/>
col2<-c(seq(from=11,to=30, by=1))<br/>
col3<-c(seq(from=21,to=40, by=1))<br/>
col4<-c(seq(from=31,to=50, by=1))<br/>
data<-cbind(dates, col1, col2, col3, col4)<br/>
class(dates)<br/>
data  #This is what my data looks like. NOTE: the "dates" field is type numeric so I TRY convert it below<br/><br/>

data[,1]<-as.Date(as.character(data[,1]), format("%Y%m%d"))#convert to date class<br/>
class(data[,1])  ### the conversion did not work. Help? The date column is still is numeric<br/>
```

Now I'd like to show a line graph with 4 lines and with the dates on the x-axis by week or month  using ggplot

any help??

#####

Thank you.

Comment: Puleese! Stop posting in HTML. It a real pain to remove all those `<br>`'s

Answer (score 5):

As @Dwin points out use a `data.frame` not a matrix because your conversion works fine.

```
e.g. class(as.Date(as.character(data[,1]), format("%Y%m%d")) )
 #[1] "Date"
```

to plot what you want using `ggplot2` you need your data long, done here using `melt()` then `scale_x_date()` to format axis by week.

```
data<-data.frame(dates=dates, col1=col1, col2=col2, col3=col3, col4=col4)
library(plyr)
data <- melt(data, id.vars="dates")
data[,1]<-as.Date(as.character(data[,1]), format("%Y%m%d"))
ggplot(data, aes(x=dates,y=value)) + geom_point(aes(colour=variable))  + 
      scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("weeks"), labels = date_format("%d-%b"))
```

[image]

Comment: no worries, remember to upvote the answers you thinks re good if you want and to accept which ever answer actually answers your question! :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix R dates with numeric columns in a matrix. Only possible to do in a dataframe:

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data$dates <- as.Date(as.character(data$dates), format="%Y%m%d")
 head(data)
       dates col1 col2 col3 col4
1 2010-11-01    1   11   21   31
2 2010-11-02    2   12   22   32
3 2010-11-03    3   13   23   33
4 2010-11-04    4   14   24   34
5 2010-11-05    5   15   25   35
6 2010-11-06    6   16   26   36
```

I never "got" the ggplot thing. Seems like a job for `graphics::matplot`:

```
png("my.png")
matplot(x=data[[1]], y=data[-1], type="l", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=data$dates,labels=as.character(data$dates))
dev.off()
```

[image]

My failed effort with ggplot:

```
> p <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=dates, y=data[,2:5]) )+geom_line()
> p
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:data[, 2:5]
```

Comment: Ok thank you for that. Can you help with the graphing part? I'd like to show the 4 lines in a line graph wiht the dates by=week or by= month.  I don't want to show all the dates because you cannot read them if they all show.  Thank you!

Comment: So I see here: <br>http://www.sixhat.net/how-to-plot-multpile-data-series-with-ggplot.html <br><br>df.melted <- melt(data, id="dates") <br><br>ggplot(data=df.melted, aes(x=x, y=value))+geom_line()  <br> but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you may be "getting" the ggplot paradigm better than I did. But that link is posing up a question I also do not understand.

Comment: +1 no reshape needed with `matplot`. Also @user3022875 I like that you ignored the html comment and continued paste them into your comments...

Comment: It's a puzzle to me that @hadley didn't try to replicate matplot's behavior in the aes() functionality. Or maybe he did and I missed the memo.